# Removing punctuation query

Tags: c++, string-formatting

I've been updating a program I wrote almost two years ago, and I've come across a call to remove all punctuation and spaces from a string.

The call works alright, but I'm not sure that it's the most efficient way to do this.

The line of code is below:

```
tempMessage.erase(remove_if(tempMessage.begin(), tempMessage.end(), (int(*)(int))ispunct), tempMessage.end());
```

I've no recollection of where I came up with this or how it was put together, but I want to be able to understand this call fully.

I get that the std::string.erase gets rid of the first argument up until the second argument. I can also see how the remove_if defines the start and end points, but can anyone tell me where the third argument in the remove_if call is coming from?

I can't remember why the (int(*)(int)) is needed for the life of me.

While you are looking at the code, can anyone improve this, or make it more efficient?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this doesn't work in general; it just seems to (and it
may work with some compilers).  You cannot pass a `char` to the
one argument version of `ispunct` without incurring undefined
behavior.

As for the reason for the cast: the standard defines both
a single argument `ispunct` function *and* a two argument
`ispunct` function template.  In order to correctly 
instantiation the template function `erase`, the compiler needs
to know the exact type of `ispunct`.  To know the exact type of
`ispunct`, the compiler needs to be able to do type deduction on
the function template.  In order to do type deduction, the
compiler needs to know the type expected.  There's a cycle in
the dependencies, which the explicite cast (or what looks like
an explicit cast) resolves.

Because using the one parameter version of `ispunct` results in
undefined behavior, and using the two parameter version won't
compile unless you provide the additional parameter (using
`std::bind`, for example), anyone doing any string processing in
C++ will have functional objects already written in his toolbox
to handle this, and would write something like:

```
tempMessage.erase(
    std::remove_if( tempMessage.begin(), tempMessage.end(), IsPunct() ),
    tempMessage.end() );
```

How you implement `IsPunct` depends on your needs with regards
to localization.  The simplest version is just:

```
struct IsPunct
{
    bool operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return ::ispunct( static_cast<unsigned char>( ch ) );
    }
};
```

The version using the `ctype` facet of `locale` is somewhat
more complicated (and you probably want it to keep a copy of the
`locale`, as well as a reference to the facet, just to be sure
that the referenced facet doesn't disappear).

Comment: It seems like I was looking for a quick fix at the time, and this did the job. Could you explain the structure you've defined in your answer a little more? It looks like it's returning true if the char is a punct character, but I don't understand the two semi-colons before the ispunct call. I'm also not very familiar with the bool operator() const implementation. Could you also expand on this? Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: No problem.  The `::` is a scope resolution operator.  It just makes sure that we get the `ispunct` from `<ctype.h>`, and not another one.  (It shouldn't be necessary here.)  `bool operator()(...)` is a function call operator: it means that the compiler can "call" the object like it would a function.  Such objects are called functional objects, or functors, and are widely used in C++.

Comment: Just for my own clarity. how is passing an `char` to `int ispunct( int ch )` undefined behavior, yet passing an `unsigned char` is *not*? Is the former not covered by the result of integral promotions in the standard (4.5/4.7), and if not, how is the latter?

Comment: @WhozCraig You can't pass just any `int` to `ispunct`.  It must be in the range `[0...UCHAR_MAX]` or `EOF`.  Unless plain `char` is unsigned (which it usually isn't, for various historical reasons), conversion to `int` will result in values outside of this range.

Comment: @JamesKanze ok. I think I understand. I knew that representation defined in C99 7.4.1, I just wasn't clear where it was in C++11. Thank you.

Comment: @WhozCraig In C++, it's in C99, included by reference.